# Data for simple TSP

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I wrote a simple genetic algorithm that can solve traveling salesman problem with 5 cities. I want to see how it does on a problem with more cities, something like 10, 25, 50, 100, but I can't find a sample date for the problem to try it on. Basically, I am looking for 2D lists or matrices with distances between cities. It would be nice if there is a solution. Where should I look?

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Do you want data with exact solutions, or just data?  You can always just construct your own data sets if you'd like.  Also, are you looking for Euclidean TSP instances, or arbitrary TSP instances?

Comment: If solutions are included it would be nice. I don't know what Euclidean and Arbitrary TSP instances are. I am just starting.

Comment: You can also create sets with known solutions to get started - for instance, create n points on a circle. The best solution is to traverse them in order, and you can approximate the ideal path length by the length of the circle.

Answer (score 9):

A well-known benchmark library for the TSP with instances ranging from as few as 14 to close to 100,000 cities is the [TSPLIB](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/). The instances have been solved to optimality, for some instances the optimal solution is also available.

Many of the instances have a real-world background such as travel been cities in Germany, Switzerland, the USA, or in the whole world. Some of the instances represent drilling problems for computer board layout There's also an instance that represents the voyage of Ulysses.

Answer (score 7):

The sources I've found online are quite huge. I might be doing something wrong, but 10 places (cities) take ~0.6s and 11 places take ~7s. The smallest known-solution dataset I could find was 15 places (and considered "small", the "classical" one being 48 places) but perhaps those are for optimized (non-brute force) algorithms. In the end I made my own table with real-world cities:

```
           m
           a
           a                           h
           s       h   s               u
           t   a   e   i   g           l
           r   a   e   t   e           s
           i   c   r   t   l   e   b   b   a       e
           c   h   l   a   e   c   o   e   n   o   p
           h   e   e   r   e   h   n   r   n   h   e
           t   n   n   d   n   t   n   g   e   e   n
maastricht 0   29  20  21  16  31  100 12  4   31  18
    aachen 29  0   15  29  28  40  72  21  29  41  12
   heerlen 20  15  0   15  14  25  81  9   23  27  13
   sittard 21  29  15  0   4   12  92  12  25  13  25
    geleen 16  28  14  4   0   16  94  9   20  16  22
      echt 31  40  25  12  16  0   95  24  36  3   37
      bonn 100 72  81  92  94  95  0   90  101 99  84
  hulsberg 12  21  9   12  9   24  90  0   15  25  13
     kanne 4   29  23  25  20  36  101 15  0   35  18
       ohe 31  41  27  13  16  3   99  25  35  0   38
      epen 18  12  13  25  22  37  84  13  18  38  0

Optimal (by program): cities 0-7-4-3-9-5-2-6-1-10-8-0 = 253km
maastricht -> hulsberg -> geleen -> sittard -> ohe -> kanne -> echt
-> heerlen -> bonn -> aachen -> epen -> kanne -> maastricht
```

The data format readable by the program is a partial table (because it's symmetrical):

```
29 20 21 16 31 100 12 4 31 18
15 29 28 40 72 21 29 41 12
15 14 25 81 9 23 27 13
4 12 92 12 25 13 25
16 94 9 20 16 22
95 24 36 3 37
90 101 99 84
15 25 13
35 18
38
```

For me this takes ~6.7 seconds to process on a 3rd gen i7 (i7-3630QM). Program is written in C++, single-threaded and simply brute-forces the possibilities. For testing it might be more practical to remove one place, then it takes ~660ms (0.7s) which is still enough to see if code changes make much of a difference.

Answer (score 3):

For next incomes, i'll paste some more "small" cases:

You can find more tests in [here](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/countries.html#WI). but the file is ".tsp" extension and you should do a simple parse that translate to the matrix of distances.

(distance in miles)

6 cities, **expected: 1248.0**

```
9999    64  378 519 434 200 
64  9999    318 455 375 164 
378 318 9999    170 265 344 
519 455 170 9999    223 428 
434 375 265 223 9999    273 
200 164 344 428 273 9999
```

15 cities, **expected: 1194.0**

```
-1  141 134 152 173 289 326 329 285 401 388 366 343 305 276 
141 -1  152 150 153 312 354 313 249 324 300 272 247 201 176 
134 152 -1  24  48  168 210 197 153 280 272 257 237 210 181 
152 150 24  -1  24  163 206 182 133 257 248 233 214 187 158 
173 153 48  24  -1  160 203 167 114 234 225 210 190 165 137 
289 312 168 163 160 -1  43  90  124 250 264 270 264 267 249 
326 354 210 206 203 43  -1  108 157 271 290 299 295 303 287 
329 313 197 182 167 90  108 -1  70  164 183 195 194 210 201 
285 249 153 133 114 124 157 70  -1  141 147 148 140 147 134 
401 324 280 257 234 250 271 164 141 -1  36  67  88  134 150 
388 300 272 248 225 264 290 183 147 36  -1  33  57  104 124 
366 272 257 233 210 270 299 195 148 67  33  -1  26  73  96  
343 247 237 214 190 264 295 194 140 88  57  26  -1  48  71  
305 201 210 187 165 267 303 210 147 134 104 73  48  -1  30  
276 176 181 158 137 249 287 201 134 150 124 96  71  30  -1
```

Hugeeee 29 cities, **expected: 27603**

imagem: [western sahara](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/witour.gif)

```
-1   74   4110 3048 2267 974  4190 3302 4758 3044 3095 3986 5093 6407 5904 8436 6963 6694 6576 8009 7399 7267 7425 9639 9230 8320 9300 8103 7799
74   -1   4070 3000 2214 901  4138 3240 4702 2971 3021 3915 5025 6338 5830 8369 6891 6620 6502 7939 7326 7193 7351 9571 9160 8249 9231 8030 7725
4110 4070 -1   1173 1973 3496 892  1816 1417 3674 3778 2997 2877 3905 5057 5442 4991 5151 5316 5596 5728 5811 5857 6675 6466 6061 6523 6165 6164
3048 3000 1173 -1   817  2350 1172 996  1797 2649 2756 2317 2721 3974 4548 5802 4884 4887 4960 5696 5537 5546 5634 7045 6741 6111 6805 6091 5977
2267 2214 1973 817  -1   1533 1924 1189 2498 2209 2312 2325 3089 4401 4558 6342 5175 5072 5075 6094 5755 5712 5828 7573 7222 6471 7289 6374 6187
974  901  3496 2350 1533 -1   3417 2411 3936 2114 2175 3014 4142 5450 4956 7491 5990 5725 5615 7040 6430 6304 6459 8685 8268 7348 8338 7131 6832
4190 4138 892  1172 1924 3417 -1   1233 652  3086 3185 2203 1987 3064 4180 4734 4117 4261 4425 4776 4844 4922 4971 5977 5719 5228 5780 5302 5281
3302 3240 1816 996  1189 2411 1233 -1   1587 1877 1979 1321 1900 3214 3556 5175 4006 3947 3992 4906 4615 4599 4700 6400 6037 5288 6105 5209 5052
4758 4702 1417 1797 2498 3936 652  1587 -1   3286 3374 2178 1576 2491 3884 4088 3601 3818 4029 4180 4356 4469 4497 5331 5084 4645 5143 4761 4787
3044 2971 3674 2649 2209 2114 3086 1877 3286 -1   107  1360 2675 3822 2865 5890 4090 3723 3560 5217 4422 4257 4428 7000 6514 5455 6587 5157 4802
3095 3021 3778 2756 2312 2175 3185 1979 3374 107  -1   1413 2725 3852 2826 5916 4088 3705 3531 5222 4402 4229 4403 7017 6525 5451 6598 5142 4776
3986 3915 2997 2317 2325 3014 2203 1321 2178 1360 1413 -1   1315 2511 2251 4584 2981 2778 2753 4031 3475 3402 3531 5734 5283 4335 5355 4143 3897
5093 5025 2877 2721 3089 4142 1987 1900 1576 2675 2725 1315 -1   1323 2331 3350 2172 2275 2458 3007 2867 2935 2988 4547 4153 3400 4222 3376 3307
6407 6338 3905 3974 4401 5450 3064 3214 2491 3822 3852 2511 1323 -1   2350 2074 1203 1671 2041 1725 1999 2213 2173 3238 2831 2164 2901 2285 2397
5904 5830 5057 4548 4558 4956 4180 3556 3884 2865 2826 2251 2331 2350 -1   3951 1740 1108 772  2880 1702 1450 1650 4779 4197 2931 4270 2470 2010
8436 8369 5442 5802 6342 7491 4734 5175 4088 5890 5916 4584 3350 2074 3951 -1   2222 2898 3325 1276 2652 3019 2838 1244 1089 1643 1130 2252 2774
6963 6891 4991 4884 5175 5990 4117 4006 3601 4090 4088 2981 2172 1203 1740 2222 -1   684  1116 1173 796  1041 974  3064 2505 1368 2578 1208 1201
6694 6620 5151 4887 5072 5725 4261 3947 3818 3723 3705 2778 2275 1671 1108 2898 684  -1   432  1776 706  664  756  3674 3090 1834 3162 1439 1120
6576 6502 5316 4960 5075 5615 4425 3992 4029 3560 3531 2753 2458 2041 772  3325 1116 432  -1   2174 930  699  885  4064 3469 2177 3540 1699 1253
8009 7939 5596 5696 6094 7040 4776 4906 4180 5217 5222 4031 3007 1725 2880 1276 1173 1776 2174 -1   1400 1770 1577 1900 1332 510  1406 1002 1499
7399 7326 5728 5537 5755 6430 4844 4615 4356 4422 4402 3475 2867 1999 1702 2652 796  706  930  1400 -1   371  199  3222 2611 1285 2679 769  440
7267 7193 5811 5546 5712 6304 4922 4599 4469 4257 4229 3402 2935 2213 1450 3019 1041 664  699  1770 371  -1   220  3583 2970 1638 3037 1071 560
7425 7351 5857 5634 5828 6459 4971 4700 4497 4428 4403 3531 2988 2173 1650 2838 974  756  885  1577 199  220  -1   3371 2756 1423 2823 852  375
9639 9571 6675 7045 7573 8685 5977 6400 5331 7000 7017 5734 4547 3238 4779 1244 3064 3674 4064 1900 3222 3583 3371 -1   620  1952 560  2580 3173
9230 9160 6466 6741 7222 8268 5719 6037 5084 6514 6525 5283 4153 2831 4197 1089 2505 3090 3469 1332 2611 2970 2756 620  -1   1334 74   1961 2554
8320 8249 6061 6111 6471 7348 5228 5288 4645 5455 5451 4335 3400 2164 2931 1643 1368 1834 2177 510  1285 1638 1423 1952 1334 -1   1401 648  1231
9300 9231 6523 6805 7289 8338 5780 6105 5143 6587 6598 5355 4222 2901 4270 1130 2578 3162 3540 1406 2679 3037 2823 560  74   1401 -1   2023 2617
8103 8030 6165 6091 6374 7131 5302 5209 4761 5157 5142 4143 3376 2285 2470 2252 1208 1439 1699 1002 769  1071 852  2580 1961 648  2023 -1   594
7799 7725 6164 5977 6187 6832 5281 5052 4787 4802 4776 3897 3307 2397 2010 2774 1201 1120 1253 1499 440  560  375  3173 2554 1231 2617 594  -1
```

Comment: Might you have forgotten the expected value for the huge one? Also, it might be good to mention whether those expected values are exact (optimal) or approximations.